# How to disable "Replace" option on long pressed of UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

```
extension UITextField {
    override func target(forAction action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Any? {

        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            if action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return super.target(forAction: action, withSender: sender)
    }

}
```

I have done with disabling "Paste" option but not able to disable "Replace" option

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the correct solution but may be useful:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

where `textField` is your desired `UITextField`.